# How to order table retrieved via .Include("table") using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, include, sql-order-by

I have this LINQ code and it works well. I can order the `Posts`, but I need also to order  the `Comments` retrieved via `Include("Comments")`: `orderby comment.DateAndTime descending`

How to achieve that in LINQ code; (ordering comments)?.

Also I am wondering if there is a way to achieve that directly in the underlying database table definition?; Comments table definition.

```
public IQueryable<Post> ListViewPosts_GetData()
{
    FacebookDataEntities entities = new FacebookDataEntities();

    var friends_A = from f in entities.Friends
                    where f.Friend_B == User.Identity.Name && f.AreFriends
                    select f.Friend_A;

    var friends_B = from f in entities.Friends
                    where f.Friend_A == User.Identity.Name && f.AreFriends
                    select f.Friend_B;

    return from p in entities.Posts.Include("Comments")
           let userName = p.UserName
           where userName == User.Identity.Name
          || friends_A.Concat(friends_B).Contains(userName)
           orderby p.DateAndTime descending
           select p;
}
```

Comment: just a hint, you can create a view in ur db and filter the view

Comment: can u show the table relation of friends, comments and posts..including columns? perhaps this is a wrong approach..

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone so this may have errors, but you should be able to do something like:

```
foreach(var post in p) post.Comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateAndTime);
```